# How to write Query with Multiple joins and having clause?

Tags: group-by, left-join, inner-join, where-clause, having-clause

Fetch all the B_NAME having EST_ID = 10 and VALUE= 0 and  EST_ID = 11 and VALUE = 1 If EST_ID exists.

In the below example,  the output should be B1,  B2.  B4 Should not be selected as it has EST_ID=12 in it.

```
ID  B_ID     B_NAME           EST_ID               VALUE
1      1          B1              10                0
2      1          B1              11                1
3      2          B2              10                0
4      3          B3              10                1
5      3          B3              11                0
6      4          B4              10                0
7      4          B4              11                1
8      4          B4              12                1
```

Comment: Stack isn't a coding site.  We help those who are stuck on something.  This question shows no research effort, or any attempts to resolve the problem by ones self.  Additionally, If any of the past 3 questions this year have helped you, you should accept an answer.  If not, explain why so those assisting could attempt a different resolution.  HINT on this question  use a where, or and a having count = 2.  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887975/matching-multiple-key-value-pairs-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching multiple key/value pairs in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887975/matching-multiple-key-value-pairs-in-sql)

Comment: @xQbert this was attempted by having clause and 'or' condition which didn't give the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what query resulted you this, but you should try adding this at the end of your query:

```
GROUP BY B_ID HAVING ((EST_ID=10 AND VALUE =0) || (EST_ID=11 AND VALUE =1)) AND B_ID <> 4
```

Comment: This will return even  B_ID = 4 ie B4 as well, which I dont want

Comment: I changed the query, check now